# Find all lowercase words in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have to to find all lowercase words in a sentence using Python. I've thought about using regular expression as follows:

```
import re
re.findall(r'\b[^A-Z()\s\d]+\b', 'A word, TWO words')
```

It works except for the case in which I have, for instance, `Aword`. How can I solve it?

In general, the regex should match the following cases:

```
Aword --> output: word
A word --> output: word
A word word --> output [word, word]
A(word) AND A pers --> output [word, pers]
AwordWOrd --> output [word, rd]
```

Comment: Just to make sure- if you have a string like `AwordWOrd` the output should be `wordrd`?

Comment: I don't understand. "Aword" is not a lowercase word, so why should the output be anything other than an empty list?

Comment: What would it do with 'Sword' as input? And why isn't 'pers' output in your last example?

Comment: Sounds like you don't want those word boundaries.  Maybe just `r'[a-z]+'`

Comment: I think the pattern `[a-z]+` . should work

Comment: @chevybow for ```AwordWOrd``` I would like the output to be [word, rd]

Comment: What about accented characters like é

Comment: It is fine without accent letters.

Comment: And what does your comment about accent letters mean? Do accented lowercase letters count as lowercase? Or are you saying that we can assume that the input is clean ASCII, with no accented letters?

Comment: @PM2Ring you can assume that the input is clean ASCII

Comment: FWIW, at the time of posting, this question was the one millionth question in the `python` tag. It may no longer be question #1000000 due to older questions being deleted or undeleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[a-z]`:

```
import re
_input = ['AwordWOrd', 'Aword', 'A word', 'A word word', 'A(word) AND A pers']
results = [re.findall('[a-z]+', i) for i in _input]
```

Output:

```
[['word', 'rd'], ['word'], ['word'], ['word', 'word'], ['word', 'pers']]
```

Comment: You may be interested in the results of the `timeit` code I just posted.

Comment: @PM2Ring Very informative solution and timings! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually *need* regex for this task, you can use `str` methods. The regex-based approach is quite fast, but it's possible to do it even faster, using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) .

Here's the fastest solution that I've found. We create a translation table (a dictionary) that maps each non-lowercase ASCII character to a space. Then we use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the resulting string up into a list; `str.split()` splits on any whitespace, and discards the whitespace, leaving only the desired words.

```
# Create a translation table that maps all ASCII chars
# except lowercase letters to space
bad = bytes(set(range(128)) - set(ascii_lowercase.encode()))
table = dict.fromkeys(bad, ' ')

def find_lower(s):
    """ Translate non-lowercase chars to space """
    return s.translate(table).split()
```

---

Here's some test code that compares various approaches, including the regex solution of Ajax1234, as well as a few suggestions from regulars in the [sopython](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) chat room, including [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin) and [user3483203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3483203/user3483203).

The test data for this code consists of strings containing `datalen` words, with `datalen` running from 32 to 1024. Each word consists of 8 random characters; the random word generator mostly chooses lowercase letters.

As [the `timeit.Timer.repeat` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat) mention the important number in these results is the *minimum* one (the first in each list), the other numbers just indicate the impact on the results due to variations in the system load.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

""" Find all "words" of lowercase chars in a string

    Speed tests, using the timeit module, of various approaches

    See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51710087

    Written by Ajax1234, PM 2Ring, Kevin, and user3483203
    2018.08.07
"""

import re
from string import ascii_lowercase, printable
from timeit import Timer
from random import seed, choice

seed(17)

# A collection of chars with lots of lowercase
# letters to use for making random words
test_chars = 5 * ascii_lowercase + printable

def randword(n):
    """ Make a random "word" of n chars."""
    return ''.join([choice(test_chars) for _ in range(n)])

# Create a translation table that maps all ASCII chars
# except lowercase letters to space
bad = bytes(set(range(128)) - set(ascii_lowercase.encode()))
table = dict.fromkeys(bad, ' ')
def find_lower_pm2r(s, table=table):
    """ Translate non-lowercase chars to space """
    return s.translate(table).split()

def find_lower_pm2r_byte(s):
    """ Convert to bytes & test the ASCII code to see if it's in range """
    return bytes(b if 97 <= b <= 122 else 32 for b in s.encode()).decode().split()

def find_lower_ajax(s):
    """ Use a regex """
    return re.findall('[a-z]+', s)

def find_lower_kevin(s):
    """ Use the str.islower method """
    return "".join([c if c.islower() else " " for c in s]).split()

lwr = set(ascii_lowercase)
def find_lower_3483203(s, lwr=lwr):
    """ Test using a set """
    return ''.join([i if i in lwr else ' ' for i in s]).split()

functions = (
    find_lower_ajax,
    find_lower_pm2r,
    find_lower_pm2r_byte,
    find_lower_kevin,
    find_lower_3483203,
)

def verify(data, verbose=False):
    """ Check that all functions give the same results """
    if verbose:
        print('Verifying:', repr(data))
    results = []
    for func in functions:
        result = func(data)
        results.append(result)
        if verbose:
            print('{:20} : {}'.format(func.__name__, result))
    head, *tail = results
    return all(u == head for u in tail)

def time_test(loops, data):
    """ Perform the timing tests """
    timings = []
    for func in functions:
        t = Timer(lambda: func(data))
        result = sorted(t.repeat(3, loops))
        timings.append((result, func.__name__))
    timings.sort()
    for result, name in timings:
        print('{:20} : {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}'.format(name, *result))
    print()

# Check that all functions perform correctly
datalen = 8
data = ' '.join([randword(8) for _ in range(datalen)])
print(verify(data, True), '\n')

# Time it!
loops = 1024
datalen = 32
for _ in range(6):
    data = ' '.join([randword(8) for _ in range(datalen)])
    print('loops', loops, 'len', datalen, verify(data, False))
    time_test(loops, data)
    loops //= 2
    datalen *= 2
```

**output**

```
Verifying: '3c/zpws% OO8Dtcgl u;Zdm{y. dx]JTyjb pj;+ ym\t O6d.Jbg8 f\tRxrbau z`rxnkI:'
find_lower_ajax      : ['c', 'zpws', 'tcgl', 'u', 'dm', 'y', 'dx', 'yjb', 'pj', 'ym', 'd', 'bg', 'f', 'xrbau', 'z', 'rxnk']
find_lower_pm2r      : ['c', 'zpws', 'tcgl', 'u', 'dm', 'y', 'dx', 'yjb', 'pj', 'ym', 'd', 'bg', 'f', 'xrbau', 'z', 'rxnk']
find_lower_pm2r_byte : ['c', 'zpws', 'tcgl', 'u', 'dm', 'y', 'dx', 'yjb', 'pj', 'ym', 'd', 'bg', 'f', 'xrbau', 'z', 'rxnk']
find_lower_kevin     : ['c', 'zpws', 'tcgl', 'u', 'dm', 'y', 'dx', 'yjb', 'pj', 'ym', 'd', 'bg', 'f', 'xrbau', 'z', 'rxnk']
find_lower_3483203   : ['c', 'zpws', 'tcgl', 'u', 'dm', 'y', 'dx', 'yjb', 'pj', 'ym', 'd', 'bg', 'f', 'xrbau', 'z', 'rxnk']
True 

loops 1024 len 32 True
find_lower_pm2r      : 0.038420, 0.075005, 0.082880
find_lower_ajax      : 0.065296, 0.083511, 0.117944
find_lower_3483203   : 0.136276, 0.139128, 0.139208
find_lower_kevin     : 0.225619, 0.241822, 0.250794
find_lower_pm2r_byte : 0.249634, 0.257480, 0.268771

loops 512 len 64 True
find_lower_pm2r      : 0.026582, 0.026888, 0.027445
find_lower_ajax      : 0.059608, 0.061116, 0.074781
find_lower_3483203   : 0.129526, 0.130411, 0.163533
find_lower_kevin     : 0.217885, 0.219185, 0.219834
find_lower_pm2r_byte : 0.237033, 0.237225, 0.237880

loops 256 len 128 True
find_lower_pm2r      : 0.020133, 0.020144, 0.020194
find_lower_ajax      : 0.059215, 0.060153, 0.076451
find_lower_3483203   : 0.125678, 0.125989, 0.127963
find_lower_kevin     : 0.215228, 0.215832, 0.218419
find_lower_pm2r_byte : 0.234180, 0.237770, 0.240791

loops 128 len 256 True
find_lower_pm2r      : 0.017107, 0.017151, 0.017376
find_lower_ajax      : 0.061019, 0.062389, 0.074479
find_lower_3483203   : 0.123576, 0.123802, 0.126174
find_lower_kevin     : 0.212917, 0.213197, 0.214432
find_lower_pm2r_byte : 0.231248, 0.232049, 0.233519

loops 64 len 512 True
find_lower_pm2r      : 0.014723, 0.014752, 0.014787
find_lower_ajax      : 0.054442, 0.055595, 0.068130
find_lower_3483203   : 0.121101, 0.121847, 0.122723
find_lower_kevin     : 0.210416, 0.211491, 0.211810
find_lower_pm2r_byte : 0.232548, 0.232655, 0.234670

loops 32 len 1024 True
find_lower_pm2r      : 0.013886, 0.014000, 0.014106
find_lower_ajax      : 0.051643, 0.052614, 0.065182
find_lower_3483203   : 0.121135, 0.121708, 0.124333
find_lower_kevin     : 0.210581, 0.212073, 0.212232
find_lower_pm2r_byte : 0.245451, 0.251015, 0.252851
```

The results are for Python 3.6.0, on my ancient single core 32 bit 2GHz machine running a Debian derivative of Linux. YMMV.

---

user3483203 has added some [Pandas and matplotlib code](https://gist.github.com/user3483203/e37990716ac6b1b01c3de461baee1004) to produce a graph from the `timeit` results.

[image: Graph of timeit results]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
import re
re.findall(r'[a-z\s\d]+\b', 'Aword, TWO words')
```